# Mutable borrow issue while looping with reference pivot

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

```
struct A {
    next: Option<Box<A>>,
}

impl A {
    fn grow(&mut self) {
        self.next = Some(Box::new(A { next: None }));
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A{ next: Some(Box::new(A { next: None }))};
    let mut p = &mut a;
    // attempt to append to the list
    loop {
        match &mut p.next {
            Some(n) => p = n,
            None => {
                p.grow();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above is the simplified logic from a more complex data structure that is able to reproduce the borrow checker complaint:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*p` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> t.rs:19:17
   |
16 |         match &mut p.next {
   |               ----------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
19 |                 p.grow();
   |                 ^
   |                 |
   |                 second mutable borrow occurs here
   |                 first borrow later used here

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Why is p still thought to be mutably borrowed in the match case?
And, trying to move `p.update()` out of the loop doesn't help:

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = A{ next: Some(Box::new(A { next: None }))};
    let mut p = &mut a;
    // attempt to append to the list
    loop {
        match &mut p.next {
            Some(n) => p = n,
            None => {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    p.grow();
}
```

I got the same error in this case. I know `p = n` is causing the problem because it compiles through without it, but why?

Answer (score 4):

Here is my take on what's going on. To explain it, I simplified your code a little, without changing the idea:

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = A{ next: Some(Box::new(A { next: None }))};
    let mut p = &mut a;
    let next = &mut p.next;
    if let Some(n) = next {
        p = n;
    }

    p.grow();
}
```

This code produces the same error as yours. What's more interesting, you cannot use `p` in any way at the end of `main`. Even `println!("{:?}", p)` produces the same error.

The compiler checks all the ways the code can execute and sees that at the point when `p.grow()` is called, `p` can either point to `a`, or to `a.next.as_mut()` (I mean inner value of `a.next` option struct). But `p.grow()` requires using one of this references.

If `p == &mut a`, and we call `p.grow()`, then the reference to `a.next.as_mut()` becomes invalid, thus error. If `p == a.next.as_mut()`, and we call `p.grow()`, we reference `&mut a` two times, as the first borrow cannot be dropped still.

If you don't assign `p = n`, there is no such issue, because there is only one valid reference, which the compiler can use when `p.grow()` is called.

In this example actually there 3 ways to prevent compiler error:

1. Remove `p = n` assignment.
2. Move `p.grow()` inside `if let` block, thus making sure that at the moment of the call `p` references the inner value.
3. Exiting `main` in case `next` is Some:

```
if let Some(n) = next {
  p = n;
} else {
  return;
}

p.grow();
```

The later works because compiler knows for sure that at the point of `p.grow()` call first borrow is not needed and can be dropped, and `p` can point only to the inner value.

The problem in the original question is same. Compiler must know for sure what `p` references at the point of the `p.grow()` call.

In the solution, provided by [Lagerbaer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/381179/lagerbaer), `p` can reference only one certain value when `p.grow()` is called (there is no reference to `p.next` at this time), thus it works:

```
    let mut p = &mut a;
    // attempt to append to the list
    loop {
        match p.next {
            Some(ref mut n) => p = n,
            None => {
                p.grow();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a very good explanation of what the borrow checker _actually_ takes issue with!

Comment: @Maxim For `p == a.next.as_mut()` case, could you elaborate on why `&mut a` is referenced twice? I guess that's what I wondered: there is only one p (there is no `next` variable in my example), when you assign a new value to p, shouldn't the old borrow in p be "released" already? After all, there is no way to effectively access a with two mutable borrows simultaneously anyway. That's why I was so puzzled by the second borrow...

Comment: The issue is not borrow itself (as shown by the 3 ways to fix the error), but the fact that the compiler doesn't know which one of the borrows is actually in use, so it must keep both valid. But calling p.grow() on one of them makes the other invalid, from the double mutable borrow perspective. Compiler just cannot drop the other borrow, even though there is nothing in the code pointing to it, because it doesn't know which one to drop.

Comment: @Maxim It's clear now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why are you borrowing in the match expression? That's unnecessary. Just match on `p.next`. That in and of itself doesn't yet move. What moves is the type of pattern you're matching. So then instead of matching `Some(n)` we match `Some(ref mut n)`.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1859dc15cdc08ddec8cac3efb6d8fa31

Comment: I'm just curious why that doesn't work... Why is it the expected behavior of a borrow checker?

Comment: When you write `match &mut p.next` you're mutably borrowing `p.next`. But borrowing a struct's field always involves borrowing the whole struct. So now `p` is mutably borrowed. That borrow is life for the whole of the match block. During this time, the only legal way to access and/or mutate `p` is through that borrow, yet you go and try to mutate `p` directly via one of its methods. That's why the borrow checker complains.

Comment: Well...I also thought it was as you mentioned. But interestingly removing `p = n` makes it through, how do we explain this phenomenon?

Comment: Plus, moving `p.grow()` (the second mutable borrow) out doesn't help in the original code... If mutably borrowed p in the scope of match was the issue, then why the outside statement in my second example still doesn't work? I think that's the part that puzzles me the most...